# Turn binary flag into -1 or +1 as fast as possible

Tags: c, optimization

When doing some bit twiddling and removing branches the following problem pops up from time to time:

Say I have an integer binary flag `f`, which can be `0` or `1`. How can I turn this into respectively `-1` and `1` (or the opposite way around, at your discretion - often either one is usable). A common way is this:

```
int i = 2*f - 1;
```

But this uses an addition and a multiplication. Can it be done any faster?

Comment: this is not a multiplication but a shift, or said differently if your compiler doesn't find an optimal way to do this whole thing, consider using a different one

Comment: did you check the assembler that this produces? did you benchmark different solutions? why do you expect that any variant would make a difference?

Comment: The answer to this would be platform and compiler specific, and you didn't specify those. I recommend sticking to `f ? 1 : -1` unless you have benchmarks for the platform you are targeting.

Comment: Jens: Most commonly it's probably an addition, not a shift.

Comment: It would be interesting, what assembly the compiler, from the different solutions, generates.

Comment: The "turn flag into 1 or -1" is commonly subsequently used to conditionally negate something. For that purpose it's actually more useful to turn the flag into 0 or -1.

Comment: @harold: in my particular case it was used to conditionally add or substract.

Comment: @nightcracker that's really the same thing.. can you post the whole problem?

Comment: @harold: in the end it was not necessary. It was for a branchless binary search, see the code: https://gist.github.com/3481295

Comment: @nightcracker why didn't you just ask for a fast integer square root then?

Comment: @harold: because I was toying, not asking for a solution :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, for starters you can do

```
int i = (f << 1) - 1;
```

Also, you could try

```
int i = f - (!f);
```

Answer (score 3):

Your original is actually pretty good - a reasonable optimiser will turn it into:

```
int i = f + f - 1;
```

and for example on x86 this can be compiled down to a single instruction.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm missing something, but what is wrong with `if (i == 0) i = -1;` ?

[Edit: Never mind, I am missing something. You want the result in a separate signed integer.]

Comment: right any decent compiler should be able to transform this into a conditional move if the instruction set supports this

Comment: I think the OP wants to avoid an if in order not to generate branching code.

Answer (score 0):

To conditionally negate `x` based on flag `f`, you can do this:

```
int mask = f - 1;  // negate if f == 0, don't negate if f == 1
x = (x ^ mask) - mask;
```

Or this:

```
int mask = -f;  // negate if f == 1, don't negate if f == 0
x = (x ^ mask) - mask;
```

To conditionally add or subtract a number, simply conditionally negate it and then always use addition.